# Sharepoint Workspace EventHandling

Tags: sharepoint, events

I want to capture the Event when a User Deletes a WorkSpace /Site , I have to perfomr some Action.
how to capture the Website deletion Event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebDeleting event, this has to be added to a web by a feature recevier (it is not possible to do this declaratively in CAML in a site definition for instance). 
Just create a feature and activate that on the sites invvolved.
It is also possible to use SEventReg, more information here:

[SEventReg](http://www.lcbridge.nl/download/seventreg.htm)